# Detecting a MOV file's duration

Tags: c#, quicktime, duration, clip, mov

I've got a client app written in C# and want to read the duration of a MOV file. I would have to create and host a Quicktime COM control in a Windows Form, then load the movie in it and get the duration. This isn't doable in my case as the client app is not a windows forms one.

Another way of doing it, which I have actually done, is to open the MOV file raw, examine the bytes until you're 12 bytes past the movie header atom of the clip ('mvhd') and get the timescale and duration from there. This hack I'm not comfortable with as it may not work if Apple changes the file format in the future.

I would prefer to avoid loading the MOV to a control as I'm only interested to get the duration of the clip and nothing else. Ideally I need to provide a string with the path of the mov file to the app and get the duration like that. Has anyone done it with unmanaged code?

Comment: Why can't you use the same COM object in a non-Windows Forms application? Or is it just a _control_?

Comment: It's a control and thus needs a host to "live".

Comment: Given the longevity of .mov, wouldn't it be safe to say that the chances of them changing the header at this point are pretty small?  Also, note that there must be scads of players out there who rely upon the same information. Find the documents that are used to define the .mov file layout and develop from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, there is no "built-in" way to deal with special file formats. You have to either parse the file yourself, or get some component to do it for you.

In fact, parsing is not a hack, provided you code adheres to the documentation. You should get (in case of some companies, buy) the **official** format specification, and parse the file header according to the specification. The specs are obligatory, so you shouldn't expect the format to change for the same filetype.

You can try to find a component which would do it for you. The library which contains a control to display the movie could also have some utility classes included. Of course the component will parse the header in exactly the same way as you would do it, so if the Quicktime format would ever change (which I personally doubt), all the components would fails the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the file raw is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Any chance you could point me to how one would go about reading the file raw?  Is this just loading the file into a stream and looping through?

Comment: @AbeMiessler Read this for a start http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_base_media_file_format. You can Google for the specs, I think ISO/IEC 14496 is the one you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

For future users reading this post, you can find the Apple Quick Time File Format document that describes the .mov file format from the following links:

[Classic Version of the QuickTime File Format Specification](https://developer.apple.com/standards/classicquicktime.html):

[Actual PDF describing the Classic Version of the QuickTime File Format Specification](https://developer.apple.com/standards/qtff-2001.pdf)

[Current Version of the QuickTime File Format Specification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/qtff.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

There is another good way to do this which will give you the option latter on to improve your application should you ever want to find the duration or other information for a quicktime .mov file plus other media containers: use the MediaInfo.dll you can reference it in your project and find the duration plus nearly all other aspects of the media file.