# Check EXACT length of Video and Audio File Windows

Tags: windows, file, explorer

for a Project I need to make sure that the lenght of my Wav File and My Mov file are the exact same. Windows just shows you the lenght in Minutes and Seconds but I need It down to the Millisecond or Frame. Anybody know how to get that information?
I googeled how to check it via Command Prompt but I couldn't find anything.

Thanks for your help

I tried looking at the Properties of the file but that's not exact enough. I tried using Command Pompts but I didn't get any info.

Comment: [Get WAV file duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114430/how-to-get-a-wav-file-duration-in-c) and [Get MOV file duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596474/detecting-a-mov-files-duration).